# Transferring file objects through queue in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, temporary-files

I have multiprocessed task that processes input data and writes results into temporary files (for usage later on). However, when I try to transfer the file handles to the parent process through a queue, it fails (no exception is raised, nevertheless the queue remains empty).

```
import multiprocessing, tempfile

def worker(i):
    my_data_object = []
    my_tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('wb')
    my_tmp_file.write(bytes('Hello world #{}'.format(i), 'utf-8'))
    my_tmp_file.seek(0)
    queue.put(my_tmp_file)

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

print('Writing...')
proc = []
for i in range(16):
    proc.append(multiprocessing.Process(target = worker, args = (i, )))
    proc[i].start()
for p in proc:
    p.join()

print('Reading...')
my_strings = []
while True:
    try:
        tmp_file = queue.get_nowait()
    except:
        print('All data are read. Queue is now empty')
        break
    my_strings.append(tmp_file.read())
    tmp_file.close()

print('Files content: ', my_strings)
print('Successful termination')
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The files remaining open seem to be causing the issue, if you call read in your worker function and close after it works:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def worker(i,queue):
    my_tmp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    my_tmp_file.write(bytes('Hello world #{}'.format(i), 'utf-8'))
    my_tmp_file.seek(0)
    queue.put(my_tmp_file.read())
    my_tmp_file.close()

q = Queue()

processes = [Process(target=worker, args=(i, q)) for i in range(16)]

for p in processes:
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()

while q.qsize():
    out = q.get()
    print(out)
```

If you tried to close the file object without reading you would get a `TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.FileIO' object` as a `_io.FileIO` object in unpickleable.

What might help depending on what you want to do is putting .name on the queue and setting delete to False and reopening the file:

```
import multiprocessing, tempfile

def worker(i):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as my_tmp_file:
        my_tmp_file.write(bytes('Hello world #{}'.format(i), 'utf-8'))
        my_tmp_file.seek(0)
        queue.put(my_tmp_file.name)

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

print('Writing...')
proc = []
for i in range(16):
    proc.append(multiprocessing.Process(target = worker, args = (i, )))
    proc[i].start()
for p in proc:
    p.join()

print('Reading...')
my_strings = []
while True:
    try:
        tmp_file = queue.get_nowait()
    except Exception as e:
        print('All data are read. Queue is now empty')
        break
    with open(tmp_file) as f:
        my_strings.append(f)
```

But you will still need to reopen the file so not sure what if any benefit there will be.